# websqlprovider.js not found in jaydata / jaydata buck?

Tags: javascript, database, uiwebview, web-sql, jaydata

i am using jaydata in a iOS uiwebview. I try to generate a websql databse because indexddb is not supported in uiwebview. The script crashes with:

Failed to load resource: The requested URL was not found on this server. 
url: jaydataproviders/websqlprovider.js

There is no websqlprovider.js file in the jaydata installation. Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 0):

you should load the jaydataproviders/SqLiteProvider.js manually, then jaydata won't try to load it automatically.
This should resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my own mistake. When i want to start a indexeddb database, then:

Providername 'indexedDb' will load the [indexDb]Provider.js file automatically from dir jaydataproviders.

When i start database with:

```
         mydatabase = new MyDB_Context({provider: Providername, databaseName : "anyname", dbCreation: MyDB.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropTableIfChanged, version: 1});
```

Sorry for this.